# What does the "Psi" in "Psi broth" stand for?

Tags: molecular-biology, microbiology, bacteriology

When making competent cells I've been using a medium called "Psi broth", which per liter consists of 20 g tryptone, 5 g yeast extract and 5 g MgSO4. Today I got curious about why it's called "psi". Is it an acronym like SOC and LB?

Answer (score 1):

Psi is the Greek letter ψ.  Psi broth is sometimes referred to as ψ-broth.

Here's an [example](http://www.clontech.com/xxclt_ibcGetAttachment.jsp?cItemId=64501&embedded=true):

> L-Broth or ψ-broth can be used instead of SOC medium, but efficiency may
>   be reduced.
>
> - L-broth： 10 g Bacto tryptone, 5 g Bacto yeast extract, 5 g NaCl, pH to
>     7.5 with 1 M NaOH, bring to a final volume of 1 L, and autoclave.
> - ψ b-broth： 5 g Bacto yeast extract, 20 g Bacto tryptone, 5 g
>     MaSO4･7H2O, pH to 7.5 with 1M KOH, bring to a final
>     volume of 1 L and autoclave.

Comment: This only partly answers the question. The key thing which is missing is where the "psi" came from. (e.g. why "psi" and not "zeta" or "epsilon" or even "gimel"?)